# jquery: if statement does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

The code below is very simple.  Basically, if variable "ret" returns a value and if the value is "fail" it should post Alert:"Trigger 2".  However, the problem is the IF statement.  It triggers the Alert:"Trigger 1" and when the conditional statement comes up, it skips it.

I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.  Thank you.

```
$(function() {
    var body = $(document).find("body");    
    body.on("submit", "#form-user-profile", function (e) {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url  = $(this).attr("action");
        $.post(url, data, function(ret) {
            alert("Trigger 1"); //  Triggers alert
            if (ret == "fail") {
                alert("Trigger 2"); //  does not trigger alert
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, if the `if` is skipped, then `ret` is not `"fail"`. Have you tried debugging to see what the value of `ret` actually is when your AJAX post completes? For instance, alerting or logging the value of `ret` in the callback?

Comment: Use Browser's Debugger tool whats been returned by your function .

Comment: @ajp15243: yes it posts as "fail" but it does the alert statement and posts the value of "ret" but when IF statement comes, it completely ignores it.

Comment: Fourth comment down may help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-en/AC11Qxht2qY

Comment: **Moderator Note:** I've cleaned up the comments here, if you wish to continue the discussion about Code Review on-topicness, then please take it to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response actually is `fail` then most likely the problem is some whitespace surrounding the response, causing the if statement to evaluate to false. This can be solved by trimming the response:

```
if ($.trim(ret) == "fail") {
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code is actually running, you should be able to view response headers from the Post URL using Chrome or Firefox dev tools. That should give you what the actual response is and help you debug the answer, I imagine its simply returning something close to what you have, but not exactly what you have.

Comment: Yes, I am actually using firebbug 2.0.4 to keep track of the responses.